# csv parsing and linkage to another row in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, recursion

I have a sample `csv` file like below, where the last column is 'friend'

```
name,department,birthday month, friend
John Smith,Accounting,November, Christoper
Erica Meyers,IT,March, None
Christoper, IT, June, Mary
Mary, Testing, March, Erica
```

I need to find the relationship in the 'friend' section and I need to provide the information of his friend

Example :
1) John Smith is a friend of Christoper and I need to print the information of christoper
2) Christoper is a friend of Mary and I need to print the information of Mary
3) Similarly Mary to Erica... 
till it reaches to None

I am a newbie in python, just exploring in it, Could someone give the hint for the best way to achieve this would be really helpful.

Thanks,
Harry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using just built-in modules, the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module is a great place to start. Usually, for problems regarding grouping data, `dict` is a data structure that lends itself to this:

```py
import csv

# I'll start with just an empty list rather
# than list comprehension
rows = []

# open your file
with open('somefile.csv') as fh:
    reader = csv.reader(fh) # set up your csv reader
    headers = [h.strip() for h in next(reader)] # the headers will be the first line, and strip them so you don't get spaces
    # You can make a list of dictionaries now
    for row in reader:
        # zip will create tuples of corresponding
        # elements in iterables, and we make a dict by
        # stripping off spaces
        rows.append({header: r.strip() for header, r in zip(headers, row)})
```

Now you have a data structure that looks like:

```py
[{'name': 'John Smith', 'department': 'Accounting', 'birthday month': 'November', 'friend': ' Christoper'}, 
{'name': 'Erica Meyers', 'department': 'IT', 'birthday month': 'March', 'friend': ' None'}, 
{'name': 'Christoper', 'department': ' IT', 'birthday month': ' June', 'friend': ' Mary'}, 
{'name': 'Mary', 'department': ' Testing', 'birthday month': ' March', 'friend': ' Erica'}]
```

Now, it might be a bit tricky to find where friends are in this list, so you can wrap the rows as a dictionary where the keys are the `names` of each person, and to avoid copying data, we can just have the value be the index of that person in the list:

```py
friends_dict = {}

for i, friend in enumerate(rows):
    friends_dict[friend['name']] = i
```

This means you can look up a specific friend quickly with just their name, and use the index to find them in the list. To find intersections, then, start at the first entry in `rows` and go until you can't find a friend anymore:

```py
row_index = 0

# this will continue until a friend is not found
# in friends_dict
while row_index is not None:
    person = rows[row_index]
    name, friend = person['name'], person['friend']
    # f-strings are a fantastic addition to python3.5+
    print(f"{name} is a friend of {friend}")
    # get the next friend
    row_index = friends_dict.get(friend)


John Smith is a friend of Christoper
Christoper is a friend of Mary
Mary is a friend of Erica
```